# Change the background color of CardView programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

The [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) has an attribute `card_view:cardBackgroundColor` to define the background color.
This attribute works fine.

At the same time there isn't a method to change the color dynamically.

I've just tried solutions like:

```
mCardView.setBackgroundColor(...);
```

or using a Layout inside the cardView

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inside_layout">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>  

 View insideLayout = mCardView.findViewById(R.id.inside_layout);
 cardLayout.setBackgroundColor(XXXX);
```

These solutions don't work because the card has a cardCornerRadius.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
CardView card = ...
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

In XML

```
 card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

Update: 
in XML

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: It seems a new method in support lib. I didn't see it the last month, may be it is an update

Comment: Might want to add that the way to configure this in XML is `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"`

Comment: Using `card_view` namespace doesn't work for me, I have to use `app` instead.

Comment: @rsicarelli All depends on what you name it: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: How can i set Gradient Drawable to card background programmatically  ?

Answer (score 117):

Use the property card_view:cardBackgroundColor:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >
```

Comment: The OP tell us about that property in the first line of his question, he said he wants to achieve it "dinamically".

Answer (score 33):

You can use this in XML

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

or this in Java

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 21):

I used this code to set programmatically:

```
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

Or in XML you can use this code:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: This answer is more usefull because contains the static (XML) and the programmatic way (JAVA) Kudos.

Answer (score 16):

I was having a similar issue with formatting CardViews in a recylerView.

I got this simple solution working, not sure if it's the best solution, but it worked for me.

```
mv_cardView.getBackground().setTint(Color.BLUE)
```

It gets the background Drawable of the cardView and tints it.

Answer (score 12):

You can use below

```
cardview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EAEDED"));
```

Answer (score 10):

The way it's set in the `initialize` method uses the protected `RoundRectDrawable` class, like so:

```
RoundRectDrawable backgroundDrawable = new RoundRectDrawable(backgroundColor, cardView.getRadius());
cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

It's not pretty, but you can extend that class. Something like:

```
package android.support.v7.widget;

public class MyRoundRectDrawable extends RoundRectDrawable {

    public MyRoundRectDrawable(int backgroundColor, float radius) {
        super(backgroundColor, radius);
    }

}
```

then:

```
final MyRoundRectDrawable backgroundDrawable = new MyRoundRectDrawable(bgColor,
            mCardView.getRadius());
mCardView.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

**EDIT**

This won't give you the shadow on < API 21, so you'd have to do the same with `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`.

There doesn't appear to be a better way to do this.

Comment: +1 for hacking and I agree. I can't find a better solution.
Anyway I hope in something different in official API.

Comment: Is this class(RoundRectDrawableWithShadow or RoundRectDrawable) accessible? I don't think so

Answer (score 8):

A little late here & partially off topic since this is not programmatically but I find it best to setup styles for Widgets and you can do this for a `CardView` just create a style it will keep your xml cleaner...

```
<style name="MyCardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
    <!-- Card background color -->
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- Ripple for API 21 of android, and regular selector on older -->
    <item name="android:foreground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <!-- Resting Elevation from Material guidelines -->
    <item name="cardElevation">2dp</item>
    <!-- Add corner Radius -->
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
</style>
```

this is using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

and then setting the style in the layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     style="@style/MyCardViewStyle">
    <!-- Other fields-->
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you need to import the appcompat-v7 library using Android studio via gradle:

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
 }
```

hope this helps. happy coding

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the XML styling. Always struggling with that. Isn't there a way to define the style in themes.xml? Then you wouldn't have to set the style for each CardView.

Comment: That is pretty awesome - I was struggling with trying to figure out how to propagate selectors down through the layout - and this was NOT working pre API21.   The ripple was working fine post API21- but your theme approach was the first time I managed to get the CardView to give the right look on clicking across the contents.

Comment: The OP tell us about that property in the first line of his question, he said he wants to achieve it "dinamically".

Answer (score 6):

**It is very simple in kotlin. Use ColorStateList to change card view colour**

```
   var color = R.color.green;
   cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.colorList(color));
```

**A kotlin extension of ColorStateList:**

```
fun Context.colorList(id: Int): ColorStateList {
    return ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, id))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way for me is this one (Kotlin)

```
card_item.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#fc4041"))
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, I was able to change the background color like this:

```
var card: CardView = itemView.findViewById(com.mullr.neurd.R.id.learn_def_card)
card.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(main,R.color.selected))
```

Then if you want to remove the color, you can do this:

```
card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Using this method I was able to create a selection animation.
https://gfycat.com/equalcarefreekitten

Answer (score 3):

In **JAVA**

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFFEFEFE);
```

android use ARGB colors. you can use like this (0xFF + RGB COLOR)--Hard-coded color.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue while trying to create a cardview programmatically, what is strange is that looking at the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardBackgroundColor%28int%29, Google guys made public the api to change the background color of a card view but weirdly i didn't succeed to have access to it in the support library, so here is what worked for me:

CardViewBuilder.java

```
    mBaseLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
    // FrameLayout Params
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams baseLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mBaseLayout.setLayoutParams(baseLayoutParams);

    // Create the card view.
    mCardview = new CardView(context);
    mCardview.setCardElevation(4f);
    mCardview.setRadius(8f);
    mCardview.setPreventCornerOverlap(true); // The default value for that attribute is by default TRUE, but i reset it to true to make it clear for you guys
    CardView.LayoutParams cardLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    cardLayoutParams.setMargins(12, 0, 12, 0);
    mCardview.setLayoutParams(cardLayoutParams);
    // Add the card view to the BaseLayout
    mBaseLayout.addView(mCardview);

    // Create a child view for the cardView that match it's parent size both vertically and horizontally
    // Here i create a horizontal linearlayout, you can instantiate the view of your choice
    mFilterContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    mFilterContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    mFilterContainer.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    mFilterContainer.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));

    // And here is the magic to get everything working
    // I create a background drawable for this view that have the required background color
    // and match the rounded radius of the cardview to have it fit in.
    mFilterContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filter_container_background);

    // Add the horizontal linearlayout to the cardview.
    mCardview.addView(mFilterContainer);
```

filter_container_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="8dp"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
```

Doing that i succeed in keeping the cardview shadow and rounded corners.

Comment: You are adding a LL in your cardview in this way and of course you can do it, but it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: The request was about changing the card background color dynamically, and i think this method does it pretty simply by changing the inner layout background color. Or am i missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same problem on **Xamarin.Android - VS** (2017)

The **Solution** that worked for me:

### SOLUTION

In your XML file add:

```
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and in your  `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` element add this propriety:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffb4b4"
```

(i.e.)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffb4b4" />
```

You can also add `cardElevation` and `cardElevation`.

If you want to edit the `cardview` **programmatically** you just need to use this code: 
For (C#)

```
    cvBianca = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.CardView>(Resource.Id.cv_bianca);
    cvBianca.Elevation = 14;
    cvBianca.Radius = 14;
    cvBianca.PreventCornerOverlap = true;
    cvBianca.SetCardBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```

And now you can change background color **programmatically** without lost border, corner radius and elevation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in java.

cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cac8a0"));

code color form http://www.color-hex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the corners to stay.  This is c#, Xamarin.Android

in ViewHolder:

```
CardView = itemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cdvTaskList);
```

In Adapter:

```
vh.CardView.SetCardBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#4dd0e1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in XML

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

or by programmatically

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_color));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna change card tint color just try this code it works for me.
For me this code works. I use it with card and image views but i thins it works in any view to change their tints colors. cardBookmark is my cardView name.

```
var cardDrawable: Drawable = binding.cardBookmark.background
cardDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(cardDrawable)
DrawableCompat.setTint(cardDrawable, resources.getColor(R.color.shuffleColor))
binding.cardBookmark.background = cardDrawable
```

Answer (score 1):

Is some cases its going to be a little tricky becase not all the time the code `cardview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red)` is going to work.

I solved my problem this way..

```
final color = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_tab_selected));
userNoteTabCardView.setBackgroundTintList(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

in the activity of fragment do this to get the color in values/color

```
  cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.alpha(R.color.gray999ea4));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MaterialCardView`, and you wanted to set it programatically then you can use this;

```
cardView.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
                    context.resources.getColor(
                        R.color.card_bg
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cardview` is a bit coy. I had list of colors in my structure and Model is like

```
class ModelColor : Serializable {

var id: Int? = 0
var title: String? = ""
var color: Int? = 0// HERE IS THE COLOR FIELD WE WILL USE

constructor(id: Int?, title: String?, color: Int?) {
    this.id = id
    this.title = title
    this.color = color
}
```

}

load the model with color, last item on constructure taking from `R.color`

```
 list.add(ModelColor(2, getString(R.string.orange), R.color.orange_500))
```

and finaly you can setBackgrıundResource

```
 cv_add_goal_choose_color.setBackgroundResource(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You only need to set card background color.**

```
yourCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

One sufficient way to change the background color for cardView is **setBackgroundResource**, You can create drawable file as well and pass to **setBackgroundResource**,

*holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_frame)*

or

*holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)*

Answer (score 0):

```
private MaterialCardView imgIgnition;
imgIgnition = findViewById(R.id.imgIgnition);
imgIgnition.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#198754"));
```

**THE Above Code Worked For Mee**

Answer (score 0):

app:cardBackgroundColor="" in xml

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

> try it works easy

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
```

Comment: The OP tell us about that property in the first line of his question, he said he wants to achieve it programmatically/dinamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
CardView cardView;

cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```