# Card View background color affects shadow color

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I have my Card View set up like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:contentPadding="10p"
```

Without a background color my Card View looks perfect like this:

[image]

However, when I add the simple property:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#xxxxxxxx"
```

the shadows change significantly in terms of color, transparency, blur etc.

[image]

How might I go about fixing this? I tried using a `RelativeLayout` as the background and changing the color there, so it wouldn't affect the shadows... but that affected the rounded corners.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem and solved it by removing the alpha portion of my hex code.

Example: #AA333333 removing the AA. Of course use the hex color that you need without the alpha.

Comment: That's exactly what caused the problem. Elimination of alpha part of color solved the issue for me.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it when the color is partly translucent(with some alpha)??

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of `RelativeLayout` is a good one. Instead of placing the card view in `RelativeLayout`, add `RelativeLayout` as CardView child, and than add its content to `RelativeLayout`, in your case it look like you got single child: `TextView`.

So change your `TextView` background color or place it in a `RelativeLayout` and change `RelativeLayout` background color.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried, except the `RelativeLayout` will fit inside the `CardView` but won't expand inside it. As a result I don't get my desired rounded corners.

Comment: @GregPeckory You can use a drawable shape to get rounded corners. Any way you should try more tower this direction, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, since the alpha is the problem, you can try to brigthen the card color (or blend it with the underlying color)

```
ColorUtils.blendARGB(yourCardColor, Color.WHITE, 0.2f)
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of that, set android:background="#hexColor"

Comment: how might I achieve this programatically ?

Comment: CardView card = findView... Card.setBackground()

Comment: I need to create a `drawable` for this. Do I just set the color there?

Comment: Sorry, Please use card.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); . Specify the RBG values inside the rgb() . setBackgroundColor takes int values

Comment: I have tried this, and it results in a large rectangle with no shadow or rounded corners.

Comment: allright. Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561122/change-the-background-color-of-cardview-programmatically

Comment: Yes, this was initially what was causing the issue

Comment: Not Exact solution.