# CardView background set using cardBackgroundColor covers shadow

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to set the background colour for MaterialCardView when it is selected. The background colour seems to affect the shadow area as well.
This is not so noticeable when the color is solid, it becomes clear when the background color is partly translucent.

I found this question([Card View background color affects shadow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392563)) where the author is ok with a solid color as background but I am not.

Is there a way to apply the background color only inside the card and not affect the shadow region?

Comment: I'm not using card view much, but how about adding another layout/view `match_parent` and use it as the background?

Comment: you can find the same approch in the link I refer to. The problem is the chlidview does not have round edges and looks ugly.

Comment: Hey you got around this issue ? I am facing the same.

Comment: No, I changed the design a little which no longer required background color for card view.

Answer (score 1):

Use background tint in XML

android:backgroundTint

Comment: it also causes the same effect as setting the cardBackgroundColor attribute