# Change Android RecyclerView Card background dynamicall

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/) article for creating cards in android. This is working perfectly!!! I want to set the background color of each of the cards programmatically.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561122/change-the-background-color-of-cardview-programmatically) post in SO but somehow i cannot use the accepted answer which says

```
CardView card = ...
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

And here is the adapter class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
        holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
    }

    public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

How can I set the color of CardView programmatically.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This snippet code not works? Can you post your Adapter class?

Comment: i have edited my question and entered the adapter class

Comment: where are the code to change color of background card?

Comment: thats precisely my question. where can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

So you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
    holder.dateTime.set

    if(position % 2 == 0){

        holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6E6E6"));

    } else {

        holder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
}
```