# Custom color drop shadow around View

Tags: android, shadow

I know that there are many questions about shadows in Android, but I didn't find the answer for my question, cause most of solutions now uses just `android:elevation` property which is useless if we want custom color of shadow.

My question is how to create custom color shadow for `View`, but without using bad looking drawables, which are just custom shapes with offset?

Comment: Have you consider using cardview

Comment: How we can change CardView shadow color?

Comment: CHeck this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561122/change-the-background-color-of-cardview-programmatically

Comment: Background color has nothing to shadow color...