# how can i assign a background to layout from kotlin

Tags: xml, android-layout, kotlin

i want to assign a background to the card view layout from recycler view adapter code by using a xml from drawable. How can i do this by use kotlin language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the background color of CardView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561122/change-the-background-color-of-cardview-programmatically)

Comment: Can you post your recycler item XML layout and recycler view adapter's code?

Comment: .setBackgroundResource is worked. Thx